# Passing in an already cancelled CancellationToken causes HttpClient to hang

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient, cancellationtokensource

I am wanting to use a `CancellationToken` to cancel a call to `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`. However, with the following setup the call to `PostAsJsonAsync` hangs indefinitely (I left it running for several minutes).

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
source.Cancel();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

try
{
    var task = client.PostAsJsonAsync<MyObject>("http://server-address.com",
        new MyObject(), source.Token);

    task.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Never gets hit.
}
```

Note that I am passing an already cancelled `CancellationTokenSource` - I have the same problem if I cancel the token using `Task.Delay` with a short delay.

I realise I could simply check whether the token has been cancelled prior to the call, but even so, I have the same problem if the token gets cancelled after a short delay, i.e., it's not cancelled before the method call but becomes so shortly after it.

So my question is, what is causing this and what can I do to work around/fix it?

**Edit**

For those looking for a workaround, inspired by @Darrel Miller's answer, I came up with the following extension method:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync2<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T value, CancellationToken token)
{
    var content = new ObjectContent(typeof(T), value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    await content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();

    return await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content, token);
}
```

Comment: You may be getting a deadlock for blocking the main thread, does it hang if you try this in a console application or if you do `await task;` instead of `task.Wait`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Same thing happens with both `await task;` and `task.Wait`.

Comment: @nick_w, what is the execution environment for this (a desktop UI app, ASP.NET, console, etc)? Also, do you use `token.Register` anywhere?

Comment: @Noseratio The real-world code that is failing is actually in a unit test, though the code in my question exhibits the issue in a console app. I'm not using `token.Register` - should I be?

Comment: @nick_w, no you don't need to use `token.Register`. I thought you might have some custom cancellation logic using it outside that code fragment. If you can reliably repro this in a console app, I'd [report it as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Internally there is a `token.Register` being called (within HttpClientHandler.SendAsync`

Answer (score 7):

It definitely seems to be a bug that you hit  You can work around it by constructing the HttpContent/ObjectContent object yourself, like this.

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
source.Cancel();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var content = new ObjectContent(typeof (MyObject), new MyObject(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();
try
{
    var task = client.PostAsync("http://server-address.com",content, source.Token);

    task.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //This will get hit now with an AggregateException containing a TaskCancelledException.
}
```

Calling the `content.LoadIntoBufferAsync` forces the deserialization to happen before the PostAsync and seems to avoid the deadlock.

Comment: +1 Nicely done. I have incorporated this into an extension method as shown in my updated question.

Comment: @nick_w, you should consider using await instead of .Wait in your extension method.

Answer (score 6):

Agree with @Darrel Miller's answer.  This is a bug.  Just adding more detail for the bug report.

The problem is that internally a `TaskCompletionSource` is used, but when an exception is thrown due to the cancellation in this specific case, it is not caught, and the `TaskCompletionSource` is never set into one of the completed states (and thus, waiting on the `TaskCompletionSource`'s `Task` will never return.

Using ILSpy, looking at `HttpClientHandler.SendAsync` you can see the `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
// System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
/// <summary>Creates an instance of  <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage" /> based on the information provided in the <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage" /> as an operation that will not block.</summary>
/// <returns>Returns <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1" />.The task object representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
/// <param name="request">The HTTP request message.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token to cancel the operation.</param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="request" /> was null.</exception>
protected internal override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request", SR.net_http_handler_norequest);
    }
    this.CheckDisposed();
    if (Logging.On)
    {
        Logging.Enter(Logging.Http, this, "SendAsync", request);
    }
    this.SetOperationStarted();
    TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    HttpClientHandler.RequestState requestState = new HttpClientHandler.RequestState();
    requestState.tcs = taskCompletionSource;
    requestState.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    requestState.requestMessage = request;
    this.lastUsedRequestUri = request.RequestUri;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = this.CreateAndPrepareWebRequest(request);
        requestState.webRequest = httpWebRequest;
        cancellationToken.Register(HttpClientHandler.onCancel, httpWebRequest);
        if (ExecutionContext.IsFlowSuppressed())
        {
            IWebProxy webProxy = null;
            if (this.useProxy)
            {
                webProxy = (this.proxy ?? WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy);
            }
            if (this.UseDefaultCredentials || this.Credentials != null || (webProxy != null && webProxy.Credentials != null))
            {
                this.SafeCaptureIdenity(requestState);
            }
        }
        Task.Factory.StartNew(this.startRequest, requestState);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.HandleAsyncException(requestState, e);
    }
    if (Logging.On)
    {
        Logging.Exit(Logging.Http, this, "SendAsync", taskCompletionSource.Task);
    }
    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Later on, through the line `Task.Factory.StartNew(this.startRequest, requestState);` we get to the following method:

```
// System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
private void PrepareAndStartContentUpload(HttpClientHandler.RequestState state)
{
    HttpContent requestContent = state.requestMessage.Content;
    try
    {
        if (state.requestMessage.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked == true)
        {
            state.webRequest.SendChunked = true;
            this.StartGettingRequestStream(state);
        }
        else
        {
            long? contentLength = requestContent.Headers.ContentLength;
            if (contentLength.HasValue)
            {
                state.webRequest.ContentLength = contentLength.Value;
                this.StartGettingRequestStream(state);
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.maxRequestContentBufferSize == 0L)
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(SR.net_http_handler_nocontentlength);
                }
                requestContent.LoadIntoBufferAsync(this.maxRequestContentBufferSize).ContinueWithStandard(delegate(Task task)
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        this.HandleAsyncException(state, task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                        return;
                    }
                    contentLength = requestContent.Headers.ContentLength;
                    state.webRequest.ContentLength = contentLength.Value;
                    this.StartGettingRequestStream(state);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.HandleAsyncException(state, e);
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the delegate in the call to `ContinueWithStandard` has no exception handling within the delegate, and no one holds on to the returned task (and thus when this task throws an exception, it is ignored).  The call to `this.StartGettingRequestStream(state);` does throw an exception:

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
  InnerException:
```

Here's the full callstack at the time of the exception:

```
>   System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) Line 1370   C#
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingRequestStream(System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.RequestState state) + 0x82 bytes  
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.PrepareAndStartContentUpload.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) + 0x92 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke() Line 59 + 0xc bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() Line 2459 + 0xb bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj) Line 2815 + 0x9 bytes C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581 + 0xd bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 530 + 0xd bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) Line 2785  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Line 2728   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) Line 91 + 0xb bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) Line 221 + 0x12 bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool needsProtection) Line 259 + 0xe bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task completedTask, bool bCanInlineContinuationTask) Line 334 + 0xc bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWithCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task continuationTask, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions options) Line 4626 + 0x12 bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> continuationAction, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) Line 3840 C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> continuationAction, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) Line 3805 + 0x1b bytes   C#
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpUtilities.ContinueWithStandard(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> continuation) + 0x2c bytes  
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.PrepareAndStartContentUpload(System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.RequestState state) + 0x16b bytes  
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartRequest(object obj) + 0x5a bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() Line 2835 + 0xd bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() Line 2459 + 0xb bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj) Line 2815 + 0x9 bytes C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581 + 0xd bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 530 + 0xd bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) Line 2785  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Line 2728   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Line 2664 + 0x7 bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Line 829   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Line 1170 + 0x5 bytes   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

I believe the intention is to not ignore it, and in the case of an exception call the `HandleAsyncException` method which does set the `TaskCompletionSource` into a final state.

Comment: Nice digging job.  So it is System.Net.Http that has the issue and not the WebApi Client library like I suggested.  I wonder if this means that if the Formatter throws an exception whilst trying to serialize the request body you will get the same hanging problem.

Comment: +1 That's some good code spelunking. In my own debugging, I did notice that the `System.Net.WebException` that gets thrown is in fact caught, though I think you are right in that `TaskCompletionSource` is not getting set correctly.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I suspect you might be on to something there. Using Fiddler, I found that there was no traffic sent out when passing in a cancelled token (as you'd expect). When cancelling the token somewhat later, the traffic did get sent but the request was cancelled as expected.

Comment: @nick_w, yes the exception is caught by the Framework code and set as the Exception on the Task.  The problem is that no one examines the Task's exception, so it is silently swallowed and the TaskCompletionSource's Task is never put into a final state.